# Programmatically adding a new row to a QAbstractListModel subclass

Tags: qt, qlistview

Within an already-instantiated QAbstractListModel subclass, how do I add a row with data in each column, and have the associated QListView display the new row?

It seems that the only way to do it is to reimplement insertRow and setData within my model, and then hack them together in some sort of sequence within another function to add a row. Must I do this? Surely Qt must make it easier to add a new row.

Thanks much!
--Dany.

Comment: Upon looking at this question again, I realize I was simply burnt out when I wrote it :P My question in simple words is: how do I add a new row to my QAbstractItemModel subclass?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just change your model's data storage, in between beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows().

For instance, let's say you have a flat list model and your model stores the data internally in a QVector m_data. You want to prepend the list, i.e. insert a row at position 0:

```
beginInsertRows( QModelIndex(), 0, 0 ); //notify views and proxy models that a line will be inserted
m_data.prepend( somedata ); // do the modification to the model data
endInsertRows(); //finish insertion, notify views/models
```

Comment: This worked just fine, and it was a pleasing breakthrough to finally see some items in my list view. However, I have spent literally a day and a half trying to figure all of this out, and now my latest problem is trying to display a 1x4 set of data. Currently it's only showing one column worth of data and none of my column headers. Do you have any pointers on what is going wrong? I am next to completely frustrated with how difficult it is to get Qt to do something as simple as list data.--Dany.

Comment: @nessup: QListView supports only one column. If you want multiple columns and headers, you need to use QTreeView or QTableView.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to do it that way. From the [docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractlistmodel.html):

> Models that provide interfaces to resizable list-like data structures can provide implementations of [insertRows()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html#insertRows) and [removeRows()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRows).

Comment: those links are dead